# Read resource file from project C# in ResXResourceReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

I have issue loading resource file. My code looks like this:

```
var reader = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\Users\work\Projects\WebApps\source\MPS\App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx")
```

Code above works perfectly fine on my machine, but that is just development, when I deploy application to a server I need to load project path dynamically. Problem that I am experiencing I cannot use `@".\App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx"` nor `@"App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx"`

App_GlobalResources is folder that is in root path of this project. Everything I tried does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a web project? If so, take a look at `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` and `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject`...

Comment: @entropic can you help me with code example? I have never used `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject` in the past

Comment: What type of project is this?

Comment: @entropic it is .resx file, and values are strings. Does that help?

Comment: No, I need the entire project type.  Not the file.  Is the project type ASP.NET Web Forms, WinForms, Web API, WPF... ?

Comment: @entropic correction ASP.NET MVC with Razor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, you don't need to load the resource file via a `ResXResourceReader`.  Instead, you can reference the resource file in a number of ways.

First, for local resources (in `App_LocalResources` folders), you can reference it in the following ways:

C# Code Behind:

```
var resourceValue = this.GetLocalResourceObject("ResourceKey").ToString();
```

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyResource" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:, ResourceKey %>" />
```

For global resources (in `App_GlobalResources`), you can reference it as follows.  In the below example, you wouldn't include the `.resx` extension in the file name, so if you had a global resource file named `ResourceStrings.resx`, you would reference it as `ResourceStrings`:

C# Code Behind:

```
var resourceValue = this.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceFile", "ResourceKey").ToString();
```

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyResource" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceKey %>" />
```

If you want to load the file dynamically, then look at [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which you would be able to call as follows:

```
Server.MapPath(@".\App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx");
```

Comment: I don't want to load specific value in this case, I want ResXResourceReader to be able to access file, I need file path loaded dynamically. Web page is fine, code is fine, I just need path to be loaded based on project physical path on a server. As I said works fine on local machine because I've hard-coded full path, but once deployed that hard-coded path will not work. I am using ResXResourceReader and Writer to allow certain people to edit file on the fly.

Comment: yes, your edit for `Server.MapPath(@".\App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx");` worked keep in mind, it should look like this: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@".\App_GlobalResources\conf\strings.resx");` value "Server.MapPath" itself does not work